# Collecting Recurring Payments with Paypal

Tags: php, html, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I have been reading a lot documentation surrounding recurring payments and PayPal. It can be frustrating at times to setup PayPal especially when you are not told of the requirements and restrictions that apply to the PayPal service you are trying to setup. I wanted to setup recurring payments because I would like to provide options for my customers. I am based outside of the U.S. and some of my customers are in the US. Is it possible to setup recurring billing for a seller account which is not a US bank? I have no problem if this feature is available to only US merchants but what I do have a problem with is that this information not being easy to find and visible to everyone.

I know we as merchants are expected to use our common sense but a little info can't hurt anyone. I have been trying to test the sandbox accounts, as seller and buyer on my site but after about two frustrating weeks, someone not connected to PayPal told me that I can't test a sandbox buyer account with a sandbox seller account through a real site. What's the point then of having a sandbox then?

Answer (score 0):

> when you are not told of the
>   requirements and restrictions that
>   apply to the paypal service you are
>   trying to setup.

Hmm? Paypal provides both API documentation and a sandbox for you to develop against.

> Is it possible to setup recurring
>   billing for a seller account which is
>   not a US bank?

Not sure - check Paypal's documents.

```
I can't test a sandbox buyer account with a sandbox seller account through a real site.
```

Why not? Just have the real site use the sanbox url/credentials, etc? I did all this a handful of years ago and I didn't have any issues. Granted PayPal's API and IPN isn't the best - it does work.

Comment: Why didn't you just ask your questions in the comment instead of placing it as a answer? As far as I can see, your questions are basically a copy of the questions I already asked. Or maybe your intention was simply to write something to prove that you are not illiterate?

Comment: Good luck with your development brah.